# How to call PXE API from protected mode (or C code)?

Tags: bootloader

I'm planning to write a bootloader for `x86` and `x64` architecture from where I wish to make UDP and TFTP calls using the PXE network stack built into the network card. I see that there's a [PXE API](https://wiki.osdev.org/PXE#PXE_API) that I can use. However, I want to write as little assembly as possible and would like to implement the UDP/TFTP communication in C (This will be a two-stage bootloader with only minimal assembly needed to transition away from BIOS and the main logic will reside in the second stage written in C). I presume that my C code can only run in protected mode whereas the PXE API can only be called in the real mode. So my question is, in order to call PXE will I have to temporarily transition back to real mode? I've heard that doing so is not without peril. Any help will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

PXE API seems to have a dedicated entry point for 32-bit protected mode called `EntryPointESP`. Since I haven't tried it yet, I am not sure about all the details, but it should work. Consult [PXE spec](http://www.pix.net/software/pxeboot/archive/pxespec.pdf) for more information.